# How do i include Ajax in my web app

Tags: java, ajax

I am currently building a web app using java, java script and google app engine. I have also done some reading up on Ajax but I am currently confused as to how to get the configurations set up and start coding for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX isn't a framework—it's a technique for web application development. Specifically, it's the use of `XMLHttpRequest` objects in JavaScript to allow your page on the client side to talk to the server, which allows you to get dynamic behavior.

I recommend searching Google for an AJAX tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to go and look at the [Ajax API](http://reloadjava.wordpress.com/2009/05/13/ajax-configuration/) and start from there! This website is included for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try referring to the below:

[Google App Engine for Java, Part 1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-gaej1/)

[Google App Engine for Java, Part 2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-gaej2/)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps for the simplest implementation:

1. get [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and include it in one of your `.html` or `.js` files
2. write a Servlet that will return a String "Hello, AJAX-ed world!" when invoked, map it to `AJAXservlet`
3. assuming everything is set up and your `AJAXServlet` is located at `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/AJAXservlet`, write this piece of JavaScript:

(you have to include it in one of your `.html` or `.js` files

```
$.get('http://localhost:8080/MyApp/AJAXservlet', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

And that's it. After invocation, a popup will appear with content "Hello, AJAX-ed world!".